# What does the `who` command result `root :0` mean?

Tags: command-line, users, documentation, who

The return value of command `who` will always include `root :0` in X Window pts. I guess it actually means the GNOME login. Am I right?

Another question is where to get this knowledge, as I don't see it in the `man who`, neither in `info who`.

#### Example

```
[root@localhost root]# who
root     :0           Sep 11 06:33 
root     pts/0        Sep 11 06:36     (:0.0)
```

Comment: What does the command `whoami` show? Are you logged in as the root user?

Comment: `whoami` just shows root. Yes I logged in with root.

Comment: Side note: logging in with root, especially to X, is an extremely bad idea. Don't do it.

Comment: @slm `[root@localhost root]# who`         
`root     :0           Sep 11 06:33`            
`root     pts/0        Sep 11 06:36 (:0.0)`

Comment: Can you run the who command and put the results in your question? I can't follow the formatting of the output when you paste it in the comments.

Comment: @strugee Thanks for your remind. Though I don't understand it that well.

Comment: Strugee is just saying that the root account shouldn't be logged into as a regular account, you should only use it when you need to do system things directly through `su -` or sudo -i ...`. Otherwise you should have an account that you use daily as a regular account that doesn't have too many privileges.

Comment: @user43312 the reason is this: let's say you're running Firefox as root under Xorg. Firefox doesn't really need privileges, but since you're giving them to it anyway, the entire machine gets compromised if Firefox is compromised. If you run Firefox under a regular account, then only the data that that account has access to is compromised, instead of the entire system.

Answer (score 4):

See `info who` (`who`'s Stallman's domain)

> If given no non-option arguments, `who' prints the following
>   information for each user currently logged on: login name, terminal
>   line, login time, and **remote hostname or X display**.

This is X display number (and might be screen number as well, like, 0:0)

Though, it doesn't contain any `root` for my pseudoterminal X windows. If you're logged in as `root`, that's probably bad from security point of view.

**UPDATE:**
Display and screen are logical concepts of X windows system. When I say here "screen" or "display" I mean X windows screen or display, not any physical device (`who` refers to X windows displays and screens, too).

[image]

The point of displays is that your computer may run several instances of X server at the same time, then they are said to be run on different displays. E.g. your normal graphical environment can be shown by X server instance 1 at display:0 and you may also have a remote desktop application such as `Xephyr` or `Xnest` starting another instance of X server at display:1 and outputting to a single window: see https://superuser.com/questions/363988/display-remote-x-session-complete-desktop-in-one-client-x-window.

X windows system was design to allow X server and X client be separated by the network. For their interaction it relies on [Berkley sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) mechanism. Each X server behaves just like a web-server (e.g. Apache) in terms of its interaction with clients. Just like Apache creates TCP/IP sockets to listen to connecting browsers, processes their requests and sends responses, Xorg creates

- TCP/IP sockets for remote X clients
- Unix domain sockets for local X clients

It processes their *requests* to draw onto the display and instead of responses sends *events* - notifications of user activity (mouse buttons clicked, keyboard keys presses etc.).

Each display corresponds to a separate instance of X Server and there's a convention for TCP/IP port numbers and Unix domain socket names, on which displays should listen. To determine the TCP/IP port number, add 6000 to the display number. For example, Display Number 1 listens on TCP port 6001 (1 + 6000 = 6001). Unix domain sockets for Xorg are typically located in `/tmp/.X11-unix/` and named appropriately.

Screens: screens were designed to handle the case, when your computer has several physical monitors, but one X server instance draws its output on both. Then first monitor is said to be screen0 and second monitor to be screen1. Xclients had to choose only 1 screen for themselves. To be honest, I never dealt with that case myself and nowadays its pretty much dead, cause with [Xinerama extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) you may have one X screen, like 0:0 span to several physical monitors as on the picture at wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for your security suggestion. Could you clarify the two terms display# and screen#? And I get a `:0` only rather than `0:0`. And a :0.0 after pts.

Comment: As the `info who` shows, it should include 4 columns, where the last column should be a remote hostname or X display. But my `who` result just shows only the first 3 columns.

Comment: @user43312 I updated my answer with explanation of X concepts. Also, see the answer by slm for good explanation of other parts of your question.

Comment: who's Stallman's domain? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Thanks, Bob and @slm, and many others who answered my question. It is really a task to read all your answers before I thoroughly master it.

Comment: @yannbane I mean that `who` utility is a part of `GNU coreutils`; GNU = Richard Stallman; Richard Stallman = `man` hater (tried to force `info` instead of it by distributing his manuals in `info` format, thus for `who` you'd better read `info`, not `man`), `vi` hater ("vivivi, editor of the beast"), the guy who fights FBI/CIA/NSA with GPL and writes manuals at least 10000 lines long and even if you read'em you won't understand a shit ;)

Comment: Yeah I know who Stallman is, but I just didn't know that he endorsed `info` over `man`. I didn't even know `info` was a thing. I'll google it.

Comment: @yannbane Well, here is sort of a proof: http://ereimer.net/rants/infosucks.htm for Stallman and `info` relationship. I like this part: "`info` is a solution to a non-problem, a fix to that what aint broke." I admit that "`man` hater" is overstatement, but he wanted to replace `man`.

Answer (score 3):

#### who

When you run the command `who` it typically shows you output like this:

```
$ who
saml     tty1         2013-09-06 22:22 (:0)
saml     pts/0        2013-09-06 22:23 (:0.0)
saml     pts/5        2013-09-07 04:28 (:0.0)
saml     pts/9        2013-09-09 01:39 (:0.0)
saml     pts/13       2013-09-10 12:20 (:0.0)
saml     pts/44       2013-09-10 22:50 (:0.0)
saml     pts/78       2013-09-11 14:49 (:0.0)
```

This is showing me that I'm logged in as user saml, and have one console (tty1) and 6 pseudo terminals (pts). Every time I invoke a shell or open a tab in gnome-terminal that constitutes a pts terminal.

#### The 4th column

The 4th column tells you 1 of 2 things. If you're locally connected then it omits the hostname and just shows you the display number and the screen number. These are denoted by the 2 digits in the string 0.0 that come after the colon (`:`). The first digit is the display, the second is the screen.

#### Display & Screen

Display # and screen # can be a little confusing, but think of it this way. A single computer can have multiple video cards and monitors hanging off of it. These video cards and screens can be setup in such a way that you could drive them all simultaneously and these values allow you to target a specific one when launching applications. In general these are always `:0.0`, or you'll see the short hand notation of `:0`.

If this were a remote connection then a hostname would prefix the colon like this: `somehost:0.0`. This is saying that there is a connection from host `somehost`'s display (0) and screen (0). This is important so that if an GUI based application were invoked within this connection, it would get displayed at this host's display 0 and screen 0.

#### Further Readings

Much of this information is in the Xserver man page and Xorg man pages.

Comment: @ChrisDown I'm afraid you are confusing display numbers and display names. Both `:0` and `:0.0` are display names and they represent the very same one. The screen number is just implicitly `0` in the first case and explicitly `0` in the second case so `:0` is indeed a shorthand for `:0.0`. In any case `who` doesn't need to reports a screen number given the fact all screens belong to the same user session.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks, retracted. X is one of the things which I have explicitly tried to avoid after having to use Xlib a few years ago.

Comment: @ChrisDown - yes that is an area that is probably the least understood by most, myself included.

Comment: @ChrisDown I absolutely "adore" those Xorg "documentation" pages scattered all around the internet (including Xorg site) like this one: http://www.rahul.net/kenton/xsites.html. Reminds me of my granny's shed: filled with details of machines, discontinued 20 years ago, cut articles from journals and newspapers, all mixed.

Comment: @Bob Xorg has exhausted my patiences on many an occasion. dwm development has been a complete nightmare in some respects, in my opinion, almost always because of Xlib. You can't abstract such a horrible interface anywhere near enough to forget about how terrifying it is. XCB doesn't make me feel much better.

Comment: @ChrisDown this is so sad. As for the Xlib - I never dealt very close with it, except while reading GTK sources, but I don't have a feeling that its concept is deadly flawed. I though that it's so annoying because of hideous implementation. Is that right? Also, is XCB so ugly, too?