# What is the :0 terminal in the who command's output?

Tags: shell, who

When I type `who` in my console terminal, I get the following output:

```
hubert   :0           2014-05-16 21:40 (:0)
hubert   pts/0        2014-05-16 21:46 (:0)
```

From `info who` I know that both `:0` and `pts/0` should name instances of the terminal. It is clear to me what `pts/0` means but I have no idea how to interpret the first line of the output.

What is even more confusing, when I type who `hubert :0`, I get:

```
hubert   pts/0        2014-05-16 21:46 (:0)
```

Comment: Although it's not *exactly* a duplicate, answers to this question may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90206/34796

Comment: Seems like a duplicate to me, why do you think it's not really?

Comment: @Barmar, you might be right.  Sometimes I feel nitpickey over non-duplicate questions that have the same answer.  While skimming the question, I expected a more substantive difference between asking about `root :0` and `:0`.  Upon closer review, the question is really just focusing on the `:0` part too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:0` is an X display name. This means they logged in through XDM on the `:0` framebuffer.

`pts/0` is a pseudo-tty, this is an `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` window.